# Use different UpdateSourceTriggers for validation and convertion

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, validation

I'm having a WPF TextBox which is bound to a (non-dependency) property of an object (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to support binding).

```
<TextBox x:Name="copyrightsTextBox"
Text="{Binding Path=Copyright, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CopyrightFormattingConverter}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

Validation is done by implementing IDataErrorInfo on the bound object.

I'd like to validate on PropertyChanged, but only convert on LostFocus. How can this be done (since only one UpdateSource trigger can be specified).

Any advise is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`PropertyChanged` for text would occur if the text is changed, so you can handle the `TextChanged` event and validate there manually.

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).ValidateWithoutUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: True, but i'd like to take away the `PropertyChanged`, to avoid updating of the property (and thereby converting).

Comment: I said it "would occur", of course you should set the binding itself to LostFocus (default).

Comment: Sure, but as the bound property is not updated, validation is done for the last updated value of the property, instead of for the input.

Comment: Really? That should not be the case. (The method would be absolutely pointless too)